# Where is the default stylesheet for Chrome extension popups and options pages?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Popups and Options Pages for Chrome extensions have an additional user agent stylesheet that adds styles similar to Chrome's own `chrome://settings` and other pages. The styles are mentioned in explaining how to [declare your V2 options page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/optionsV2#step-1):

> chrome_style (boolean) - optional
>
> If true, a Chrome user agent stylesheet will be applied to your options page. The default value is false, but we recommend you enable it for a consistent UI with Chrome.

Is that stylesheet a stable API?

Where is that stylesheet?

Comment: Though I found the stylesheets, I'm still curious whether anyone knows the answer to, "Is that stylesheet a stable API?"

Comment: I wouldn't use this option -- even Google's popular extensions don't use it. If you want the inputs and buttons to have the same look, then you can copy the CSS over, but keep `chrome_style: false`. Setting it to `true` provides a terrible experience IMHO: not only is the options popup tiny, it also has to open the extension details tab first.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the answer in Chromium source. The following two stylesheets are added to Options Pages with `chrome_style:true`:

- extension.css:
  https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/extensions/renderer/resources/extension.css
- extension_fonts.css:
  https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/extensions/renderer/resources/extension_fonts.css