# Chrome extension UI resizes / uses smaller values in production

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

This is a really weird bug that has already consumed half of my day.
I am creating a chrome extension and when developing the extension locally it looks fine (like I want it to look).
However, once I load the extension to chrome to test performance the UI looks a lot smaller.

**I made sure both windows are at 100% size.**

What is weird is that actual values change. Font that should be `16px` in development becomes `12px` in "production".

I have attached 2 screenshots:

DEVELOPMENT (How it is meant to look):

[image]

PRODUCTION (How Chrome renders it, once the extension is uploaded):

[image]

There you can clearly see the changes in font size and UI. Is this a known Chrome bug or something?

Any help or hint is appreciated since I feel kind of stuck!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

maybe the answer of this thread could help you:
[LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41622367/where-is-the-default-stylesheet-for-chrome-extension-popups-and-options-pages)

Seeing the images you attached, I can only assume that an ancestor tag (it could be the button or an even more ancestor element) uses a font size that conflicts with your "font-light" class declared 16px.

If by "testing locally" you mean opening the html page with chrome outside of a **loaded** unpackaged extension, then accept my advice to review your method.

The same html + css combo loaded in Firefox (almost certainly) would give an even different result.

It is also possible that the issue\solution lies somewhere else, but the concepts just outlined need to be taken into consideration.